# setting focus back to a textbox

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to check if a text box is empty/null or blank before my user moves onto the next field on the user form. here is the code that checks if the textbox is empty/null/blank. My issue is that it does not return the focus to the textbox, but moves onto the next field in the user form.

```
Private Sub txtTDYLocation_lostfocus()
Dim Pcase As String
    'converts text to proper case
    
    If Trim(txtTDYLocation.Value & "") = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter TDY location", vbOKOnly
        txtTDYLocation.SetFocus
    Else
        Pcase = Me.txtTDYLocation
        Pcase = StrConv(Pcase, vbProperCase)
        Me.txtTDYLocation.Text = Pcase
        Me.txtTDYLocation = StrConv(Me.txtTDYLocation, 3)
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Are there other controls (textboxes) in that form that use a `_lostfocus` event? Because if you use that technique for multiple text boxes and every textbox tries to pull the focus whenever it loses focus they might interfere. • Put a break point in this procedure and if the code stops there go through the code step by step using F8 and check if `.SetFocus` sets the focus correctly and what happens next in your code execution (maybe somthing else is pulling focus back).

Comment: a) Use the `Exit()` event and b) `If IsNull(txtTDYLocation.Value) Then ...`. The later checks if only empty spaces as well.

Comment: @KostasK A textbox value is never `Null` therefore `IsNull(txtTDYLocation.Value)` will always return `False`.

Comment: @PEH The `Value` property is a variant and its default value is null. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.textbox.value

Answer (score 1):

For this to work you should use the event `txtTDYLocation_BeforeUpdate` and cancel the change if value is **Null** in the textbox. Once Cancel is set to **True** the focus will not be able to leave the textbox.

```
Private Sub txtTDYLocation_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If Trim(txtTDYLocation & "") = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter TDY location", vbOKOnly
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

And in `txtTDYLocation_AfterUpdate()` you can change the value.

```
Private Sub txtTDYLocation_AfterUpdate()
    Dim Pcase As String
    'converts text to proper case
    If Trim(txtTDYLocation.Value & "") <> "" Then
        Pcase = Me.txtTDYLocation
        Pcase = StrConv(Pcase, vbProperCase)
        Me.txtTDYLocation.Value = Pcase
        Me.txtTDYLocation = StrConv(Me.txtTDYLocation, 3)
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes I have multiple textboxes that are sub with "lostfocus". Thanks to Micke, I will update every one of them with "before update" and "after update". I don't know how to mark Micke's answer as my choice, but Micke has my two thumbs up! for his/her help.